# Continuous distribution depending on the rollof a 4-sided die

Tags: probability

You will roll 4-sided die and then choose a number from a continuous distribution depending on the roll. If the roll is n then the distribution is f_X (x)=(2/n^2)*x  for 0≤x≤n. Let Y=n+X.

FindP(roll=2|Y<3.5).

How do I do this? Can you show me how to do this or at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Outline:** Let $A$ be the event the roll is $2$, and let $B$ be the event $Y\le 3.5$. We want the conditional probability $\Pr(A|B)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

We need to find $\Pr(A\cap B)$ and $\Pr(B)$. The second is more work. The event $B$ can happen in $4$ pairwise disjoint ways: (i) we rolled a $1$ and $Y\lt 3.5$; (ii) we rolled a $2$ and $Y\lt 3.5$; (iii), (iv).

Each of the $4$ probabilities is not hard to compute, and some are very easy.  For example, for the probability we rolled a $3$ and we have $Y\lt 3.5$, we want $\frac{1}{4}$ times the probability that the random variable with density function $\frac{2}{3^2}$ on $[0,3]$ is less than $0.5$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You saved my life.

Comment: You are welcome. For conditional probability problems, the basic *structure* of the solution is usually identical to the one I used. The calculations of $\Pr(B)$, $\Pr(A\cap B)$ may be simple, or a little more complicated, as in this case.